# Jasmine / Karma HTTP not mocked as expected (Angular Controller on REST call)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

i've been searching around for the last days but i cannot get closer to the solution. I try to mock the http response requested by the angular controller.

angular controller:

```
myController = function ($http, appConfig) {

$http.post(appConfig.restPath+"/administration/imports", {

}).then(function(data){
    $scope.pagination = data;
    $scope.totalItems = data.data.content.length;
    $scope.totalPages = data.data.totalPages;
    $scope.pages = [];
    $scope.imports = data.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalPages; i++){
        $scope.pages.push(i);
    }
});
}
```

and the test:

```
describe('Controller: myController', function() {

// load the controller's module
beforeEach(module("myModule"));

var controller,
    scope, httpBackend, myPost;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    myPost = httpBackend.whenPOST('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports').respond({data: {content: ["a", "b"], totalPages: "1"}}, "");
    scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    createController = function() {
        return $controller(myController, {'$scope' : scope });
    };

}));

afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it('should browse the list of imported files', function() {
    httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports');
    var controller = createController();
    httpBackend.flush();

});
});
```

But it seems that he wants to ask the server for the real data when i inspect the test in the chrome console (network traffic -> HTTP requests shows me, that he is requesting the server instead of loading the mocked data...), but he receives 403 (forbidden).

the error i receive by karma is the following:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at myController.js:35:40`

line 35 is:

```
 $scope.totalItems = data.data.content.length;
```

that makes me think that he tries to load the data from the REST service, receives 403, empty result (means `data == {}`) and then he tries to access on `data.data.content.length` which is undefined....

as you can see i did it exactly like google it recommends...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Other examples on SO or anywhere else look quite similar. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear how this happens because real requests shouldn't be performed in unit tests, the fact that you have an access to mocked `$httpBackend` suggests that real `$httpBackend` is already unavailable at this moment. This may happen in an app that misuses `angular.injector` or something like that, not in a normal app. Can you recreate the issue on Plunker or Jsfiddle? Btw, `myController` here `$controller(myController, {'$scope' : scope })` is not defined, but it isn't related to the problem.

Comment: i cant get the fiddle working bro...http://jsfiddle.net/E64Se/106/

Comment: It uses Jasmine 1.3 and not 2, not sure how it expects to bootstrap the tests. Here is a template for plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/ICFsukgLrM45mwROZEqi?p=info

Comment: thank you very much! i updated the plnkr and now it is the same error like at my place...http://plnkr.co/edit/lj1kiEao4zmq8z2l3dZr?p=preview

Comment: Not exactly. It is certainly mocked fine and doesn't do real 403 request. The error is caused by the fact that `respond` [accepts data argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when) and should be `.respond({content: ["a", "b"], totalPages: "1"}, "")`

Comment: this is working! Damn i love you!

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to provide the real data or at least you can provide a prototype pf your data because you are testing that unit and it requires length.

and remove this part because you are mocking it twice

```
httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports');
```

use

```
myPost = httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports').respond({data: {content: ["a", "b"], totalPages: "1"}}, "");
```

this way you make sure that post is being called but if you still get same error then  you have to check respond data.

Comment: and how can i achieve that? how can i give karma tests the permission to access database? or how can i set up that prototype?

Comment: yes, that was what i also thought about, but removing that line results in the same error

Comment: now the error is `Error: Unexpected request: POST http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports
 No more request expected`

Comment: that means there is some problem in mocking url  i.e 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports' is not correct

Comment: but `appConfig.restPath+"/administration/imports` equals `localhost:9000/api/v1/administration/imports`

Comment: expect post means mean that has to be called if not then problem is with url i.e it is not being used

Comment: and i dont need the httpBackend.whenPost anymore?

Comment: "when" will not throw an error if not called but "expect" will so if you are sure that there will be a request use "expect" otherwise for conditional call use "when"